# Force NASM to use quadwords

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, instructions, instruction-encoding

In gas, I can do `movabs rcx, 0x402041`, which assembles to `48b941204000`.  NASM doesn't support `movabs`.  I've tried doing `mov rcx, 0x402041`, and `mov rcx, QWORD 0x402041`, but, in either case, NASM assembles it to `b941204000` which disassembles to  `mov ecx, 0x402041`.

Even though the result is the same, for my application, I need the assembler to do the full `movabs` equivalent, with identical bytes.  How can I tell NASM to do this?

Comment: `mov rcx, strict qword 0x402041`

Comment: Or `strict dword 0x402041` to keep 64-bit operand-size, but use a normal-sized sign-extended immediate which is actually 7 bytes.  The question omitted the high 4 bytes of the immediate for `movabs`, so I'm wondering if a huge long instruction is actually desired.